# Get client IP using Nginx on EC2 under Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an EC2 instance running Nginx + Gunicorn + Django placed under an Elastic Load Balancer. The ELB is enabled for dualstack (IPv4 and IPv6 addresses). I have set the following config in Nginx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Within Django views I am trying to get IP address as follows:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

This is returning the private IP of ELB instead of client IP.